# Switching style between two elements on photo gallery change

Tags: javascript

So I have a photo gallery on my front page that switches between two images; each image links to a different page. Now, beside that gallery I have two links that go to the same two pages. The idea is that when image A is showing, side-link A should be highlighted with a border. The issue I keep running into is that once I get either side-link to be highlighted, I don't really know how to get it unhighlighted. Instead of switching with the images, they just stay highlighted.

```js
var debugLink = "#firstLink";

function displayNextImage()
{
 index++;
 
 if(index >= indexgalpics.length)
 {
  index=0;
 }
    //---this is where I set the var debugLink which is 
    //   supposed to carry the selected linke
 if(index == 0)
 {
  console.log("first link selected");
        //---when image A is showing, top side-link should be highlighted
        //---ok so we know this much works, it seems these double equal
  //   signs are very important here.
  //---makeActive();
  //---but once makeActive() is called here, it makes the first link 
  //   active for the entire time.
  //---we can't put the entire style code here because same as before,
  //   it just keeps the link highlighted forever
  debugLink = "#firstLink";
  //---ok so i can set a var at top to a value in the makeActive() function,
  //   but i think the way JS works highlights either one forever
  debugLink = "#firstLink";
 }
 else if(index == 1)
 {
  console.log("second link should be selected");
        //---when image B is showing, bottom side-link should be highlighted
  debugLink = "#secondLink";
 }
 showImg();
}

function makeActive()
{
 var activeLink = document.querySelector(debugLink);
 //---adds style to the debugLink
}
```

The function makeActive() is called in the function showImg(), and the function displayNextImage() is called in another function that sets the timer.

Comment: You don't show enough code to know what's going on. For example, I don't see anything that makes a link *inactive*, which may be why your highlighting persists longer than it should.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your approach a little bit by using a boolean for the index, because you seem to only need two states.

Here is a revised version:

> **Note:** In this code, I've used custom-made functions to make the code easier to read. I created `hasClass(el,class)`, `addClass(el,class)`, `removeClass(el,class)`, `toggleClass(el,class,bool)`. You can find them in the final JS Fiddle.

```
// Register the link elements
var links = {
    true : document.getElementById('firstLink'),
    false : document.getElementById('secondLink')
},
    // Keep track of selected link (replaces your 'index')
    leftLinkActive = false,
    // Just so you don't go get it every time
    gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');

// Let's trigger the gallery
displayNextImage();

// We'll change the active link and show the correct image
function displayNextImage(){
    leftLinkActive = !leftLinkActive;

    if(leftLinkActive){ console.log("first link selected"); }
    else{ console.log("second link selected"); }
    makeActive();
    showImg();
    // Let's do that again in 2 seconds
    setTimeout(displayNextImage,2000);
}

// Add / remove the active class
function makeActive(){
    addClass( links[ leftLinkActive ], 'active-class');
    removeClass( links[ !leftLinkActive ], 'active-class');
}

// Change the image with a small fadeOut transition
function showImg(){
    addClass(gallery,'fadeOut');
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Here we switch from img1 and img2
        gallery.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+(leftLinkActive?'im1.jpg':'im2.jpg')+')';
        removeClass(gallery,'fadeOut');
    },200);
}
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo